# ブラウザでマイク以外の音を録音できるか

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-apps, chrome-extension

現在、ブラウザ(主にchrome)でマイク以外の音を録音する方法を探しております。

getUserMediaを用いることでマイクからの録音には成功しているのですが、
ブラウザを介さず出力されている音声(システム音やゲーム音等)も録音したいと思っております。

解決法としては、
・クライアントに録音用アプリケーションを入れておく
・仮想デバイスを入れてコントロールする
という方法が可能だとは思っているのですが、
マルチプラットフォームで使いたいということと、
ブラウザから録音したものを送信したいため、
ブラウザでの処理を作るだけで完結させたいです。

ブラウザでマイク以外の音も録音する方法はあるでしょうか？
これを解決できそうなAPIやchromeのapps・プラグインを作れば解決できるといった情報をを教えて頂きたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

ブラウザのみの録音は不可能です。
もしMacOSをお使いであれば、Soundflowerという仮想デバイスを利用してシステム音を録音することが可能です。